# Need to know if a person comes to my website from a link inside my website, not an external website

Tags: php, http-referer

I need to know if a person comes to my website from a link inside my website, not an external website. To be more precise, the links need to resemble something like

```
http://localhost/library/cat/5/fashion
http://www.mywebpage.com/library/cat/4/design

http://localhost/library/publication/7/pronto
http://www.mywebpage.com/library/publication/7/pronto
```

How do i find out if the HTTP_REFERER contains at least 'library/cat' or 'library/publication', and it's an internal link (comes from my live host, or localhost)?

Here's what i did so far

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER') ) {

    //if the referer contains something that resembles the above url's, add icon to go back

}
```

Comment: that's the ONLY way you can (sometimes) detect "from external" access, and it's far from reliable. not all browsers send referers, not all sent valid/real referers, etc..

Comment: i've edited my original post so it's a question, not a statement.

Comment: I would second Marc B, the referrer is not reliable, I would discourage you using this method

Comment: I understand the reliability issue. But in my case, it's not consequential at all. If the url matches then i show a back button to the url, if not, or if the referer doesn't exist or else, i don't show anything. Worst case scenario, nothing will be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your aproach is ok, but bear in mined that TRASTING ANY EXTERNAL DATA is not reliable and prone to hacks.

Using HTTP_REFERER, this is what I would do:

```
if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), '/library/cat/' ) !== false ) {

//if the referer contains something that resembles the above url's, add icon to go back

}
```

But if you really want to give the users a "Go Back" button, you have better solutions:

Use simple history(-1) in JS, thou this can send the user back to the search engine he came from:

```js
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

Your second option will be to relly on Cookies, this is a little bit more complicated but will give you the main idea

```
if (empty($_SESSION['current_page'])){
    // This is our first page in this website!
    $_SESSION['current_page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
} else {
    // This is our second+ page in this website, we have a back button
    $_SESSION['prev_page'] = $_SESSION['current_page'];
    $_SESSION['current_page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Now with this example you can play with, you can make it as an array to have more the one History event and etc.

Comment: I like the JS solution a lot! It brings you back to the exact place, that's even better. Maybe I should also test the domain of the referrer so i don't send back to the search engine. Like i've said on an earlier comment, worst case scenario, if conditions are not met, i dont show anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this is to append a random token to your internal url and check for a match on the receiving url. There are many ways to do this, most commonly storing the value in the sesson or in a database in addition to appending it to your url, and then checking the value of the url token against your stored token on the receiving end.

```
 somelink.com?token=$yourRandomToken
```

Comment: This approach is similar to the CSFR token provided with laravel, you might look into laravel or CSFR methods as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$subject = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER');
$pattern1 = '/^http:\/\/([\w.]*)\/library\/cat\//';
$pattern2 = '/^http:\/\/([\w.]*)\/library\/publication\//';

if( 1 == preg_match($pattern1, $subject, $matches) or 1 == preg_match($pattern2, $subject, $matches) ){
    // Do stuff
}
```

If you need to know whether it's local host or www.mywebpage.com that will be in  $matches[0].

Or...

```
$subject = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER');
$pattern = '/^http:\/\/([\w.]*)\/(library\/cat|library\/publication)\//';
if( 1 == preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches) ){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Where `$matches[0]` is the host and `$matches[1]` is now "library/cat" or "library/publication".

Take a look at [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and test the patterns out for yourself at a website like [this](https://regex101.com/).